# how to integrate the Ads in App

Tags: java, android, integration, ads

I am new  in Android developer so i am trying to integrate ads on my App but some error is coming.Can you please tell me how to add  codes lines of  ads in proper way on App.Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.adbuddiz.ads"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/hanumanji1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".HanumanActivity" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pause_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:text="@string/pau"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/play_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/pl"
            android:textColor="#ffff00" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/de"
        android:textColor="#ffff00" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize= "BANNER"
        ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATER"
        ads:LoadAdOnCreate="true"/>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

This is Java Class

```
   @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hanuman);
            AdBuddiz.setLogLevel(AdBuddizLogLevel.Info);    // log level
            AdBuddiz.setPublisherKey("a91379f7-dba2-4bd4-a60b-92f0b9700f3d"); // replace with your app publisher key
            AdBuddiz.setTestModeActive();                   // to delete before submitting to 
              AdBuddiz.cacheAds(this); // this = current Activity
```

Logcat error

```
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): Process: e.hanuman, PID: 1778
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{e.hanuman/e.hanuman.HanumanActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at e.hanuman.HanumanActivity.onCreate(HanumanActivity.java:72)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     ... 11 more
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/e.hanuman-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/e.hanuman-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
04-01 04:07:40.330: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: have you add mopub library for ads?

Comment: how did you insert the library ? With a jar file in your lib folder or by the java build path. And did you declared it in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400785/error-inflating-class-com-google-ads-adview-inflateexception

Comment: yes i had added the jar file in reference lib by java build path and i also declared in  AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Try this code just add this activity and use it's SetupAds() method where u want to display add mob

    package com.YourPackageName;
    import com.google.ads.Ad;
    import com.google.ads.AdListener;
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
    import com.google.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.ads.AdView;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
   import android.app.Activity;

   public class AdMobMainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener
   {
public AdView adView;
    public String ADV_PUB_ID = "Your Key";
    private boolean adVisible = true;
    LinearLayout layout;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("Admob", "Calling External");
}

public void SetupAds(){ 
Log.i("AdMob", "Start Setup");
layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM | android.view.Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   //To put AdMob Adv to Bottom of Screen
Log.i("AdMob", "End Layout Setup");

addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADV_PUB_ID);
adView.setAdListener(this);
Log.i("AdMob", "Init complete Adview");

layout.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Log.i("AdMob", "Done AddView Layout");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest();    

request.addTestDevice("Your Device Id");

//request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
request.addKeyword("LifeOK");

adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Log.i("AdMob", "End Setup");    

}
private Handler handler = new Handler() 
{
    public void  handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case 0:     //Disable Adv
                if (adVisible)
                    adVisible = false;
                break;

            case 1:     //Enable Adv
                if (!adVisible)
                {
                    Log.i("AdMob", "Case 1");                       
                    adVisible = true;
                }
                break;

            case 2:     //Enable but Hide Adv
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);                
                break;

            case 3:     //Enable but Show Adv
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void DisableAds()
{
    Log.i("AdMob", "Request Disable Adv");
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

public void EnableAds()
{
    Log.i("AdMob", "Request Enable Adv");
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
}

public void HideAdv()  //Enable Adv but Hide
{
    Log.i("AdMob", "Request Hide Adv");
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
}

public void ShowAdv()  //Show Adv
{
    Log.i("AdMob", "Request Show Adv");
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
}

@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AdMob", "Dismiss Screen");
}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AdMob", "failed to receive ad (" + arg1 + ")");    
}

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AdMob", "Leaving Application");
}

@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AdMob", "Present Screen");
}

@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AdMob", "Adv Received");
  }
}
```

//And Add  SetupAds() in your oncreatemethod in acitivty"